# Python: Pandas Timedelta for one month

Tags: python, pandas, timedelta

Is there a way to do a Timedelta for one month?

Applying `pd.Timedelta('1M')` yields `Timedelta('0 days 00:01:00')`.

Is there a code word for month?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Timedelta` is for absolute offsets. A month "offset", by definition, might have different lengths depending on the value it's applied to.

For those cases, you should use `DateOffset`:

`pandas.DateOffset(months=1)`

Functional example:

```py
import pandas as pd
pd.Timestamp('2022-09-29 00:27:00') + pd.DateOffset(months=1)
>>> Timestamp('2022-10-29 00:27:00')
```